# Newbie needs help on query (MYSQL)

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm new here and nearly new in SQL.

My problem:
I've a table (T1) with

`Datetime, CostNo, Amount`

second table (T2) with

`Date, CostNo, BillNo`

In the query should be

`Date, CostNo, BillNo, Amount`

My problem are several BillNos for the same CostNo the same day.

I need a kind of sorting the BillNo according to the Datetime.

T1 f.e.:

```
2018-11-02 11:14:52 3637    24.10  
2018-11-02 11:16:43 965     2.50  
2018-11-02 11:40:28 2552    3.50  
2018-11-02 11:40:51 2552    3.00  
2018-11-02 11:41:10 2552    3.50  
2018-11-02 11:41:36 2552    3.00  
2018-11-02 11:55:03 980     3.00  
2018-11-02 11:59:11 1976    3.00
```

T2 f.e.:

```
2018-11-02  3637    26189  
2018-11-02  965     26190  
2018-11-02  2552    26191  
2018-11-02  2552    26192  
2018-11-02  2552    26193  
2018-11-02  2552    26194  
2018-11-02  980     26195  
2018-11-02  1976    26196
```

so my query:

```
select
T2.BillDate,
T2.CostNo,
T2.BillNo,
T1.Amount
from 
    `T2`,
    `T1`
where
    T1.CostNo =T2.CostNo
    AND DATE(T1.BillDateTime) = T2.BillDate
```

works fine until CostNo 2552:

```
2018-11-02  3637    26189   24.10  
2018-11-02  965     26190   2.50  
2018-11-02  2552    26191   3.50  
2018-11-02  2552    26191   3.00  
2018-11-02  2552    26191   3.50  
2018-11-02  2552    26191   3.00  
2018-11-02  2552    26192   3.50  
2018-11-02  2552    26192   3.00  
2018-11-02  2552    26192   3.50  
2018-11-02  2552    26192   3.00  
2018-11-02  2552    26193   3.50  
2018-11-02  2552    26193   3.00  
2018-11-02  2552    26193   3.50  
2018-11-02  2552    26193   3.00  
2018-11-02  2552    26194   3.50  
2018-11-02  2552    26194   3.00  
2018-11-02  2552    26194   3.50  
2018-11-02  2552    26194   3.00  
2018-11-02  980     26195   3.00  
2018-11-02  1976    26196   3.00
```

This should be the result:

```
2018-11-02  3637    26189   24.10  
2018-11-02  965     26190   2.50  
2018-11-02  2552    26191   3.50  
2018-11-02  2552    26192   3.00  
2018-11-02  2552    26193   3.50  
2018-11-02  2552    26194   3.00  
2018-11-02  980     26195   3.00  
2018-11-02  1976    26196   3.00
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please provide a relevant and minimal sample data showcasing your requirements, and expected output. Please go through this link once: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/2469308)

Comment: Why are "amount" and "billno" in separate tables, yet related to the same costNo? Surely the amount relates to a specific bill? It's not clear whether the problem is in your data structure, or just your query. Please provide some sample data from each table, and also show the expected result of the query. Thanks.

Comment: Please review https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html and post your attempted query.

Comment: There is an example in this tutorial (orders>>orderdetails) http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-group-by.aspx which looks similar to what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the update. But 1) what did you want it to output instead? And 2) Can you please answer my question from the comment above, so we can clarify the semantics of the data structure.

Comment: P.S. You should really use proper [inner join](http://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/sql-server-inner-join/) syntax...whoever taught you that comma-separated syntax is giving you out of date / poor quality information about how to write your query.

Comment: Sorry, but it's a horrible data structure. It's not mine, but I've to suffer from it. There is of course no reason, why amount and billno are in seperate tables, but I won't change the data structure, cause it's a running system and very complexe.

Comment: I don't understand the difference between inner join / on and comma / where. Isn't it another notation for the same thing?

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing that you want:

```
select T2.BillDate, T2.CostNo, T2.BillNo, T1.Amount
from `T2` join
     `T1`
     on T1.CostNo = T2.CostNo and DATE(T1.BillDateTime) = T2.BillDate
order by T!.CostNo, T1.BillDateTime DESC;
```

First note the proper use of `JOIN`.  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit, **standard** `JOIN` syntax.

Second, if you want the results in a particular order, then your query should have an `ORDER BY` clause.  SQL tables and result sets (with no `ORDER BY`) represent *unordered* sets.  So, you need an `ORDER BY`.  I am guessing you want to keep all the `CostNo`s together, and then within each, ordered by the date/time.

Comment: OK, another code, looks good or even better then mine, but didn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

OK thanks for the help. I found a solution by myself.
Here it is, if someone will know it:
The BillNo from the 2. table is linked to the DateTime of table 1
So I build a temporaray table from table 1 with SUM/GROUP BY and ORDER BY on DateTime and add a row ID (auto_increment).
Next I build a temporary table from table 2, order by BillNo and add a row ID.
Now I can do a query with T1.ID = T2.ID and that's it.

Feel free to post a better and/or shorter solution.